# Fetch API working in options API but not in compositions API

Tags: json, fetch, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-options-api

I have some code that I want to convert from options API to composition API and in composition API I'm getting **res.json is not a function** error while the same code is working fine in options API.

**Here's the code for options API**

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'ProductComponent',
  data(){
    return {
      productData: []
    }
  }
  methods: {
    async retrievedData(){
      const res = await fetch('../productsInfo.json');
      const resData = await res.json()
      this.productData = resData
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Here's the code for composition API**

```
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'ProductComponent',
setup() {
  const  productData =ref([])
  const retrievedData = async() => {
    const res = await fetch('../productsInfo.json');
    const resData = await res.json()
    productData.value = await resData
  }
}
</script>
```

Not using return for productData and retrievedData in setup method because this data is not being exposed.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for `script` + `setup()` syntax? The recommended approach is via `<script setup>` and is much easier and readable.

Comment: You have not returned the data. I think you just need to add `return { productData, retrievedData }` in `setup()`.

Comment: As i mentioned above this data is not be being used directly in template so there is no use of returning this data, I'm parsing this data and using the parsed data for graph using chart.js which is initialized in onMounted life-cycle hook.
My problem is that res.json() why is it working in options api and not compositions api.

Comment: I have try to implemented your code in composition api and for me it's working fine. Here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8bfzkm?file=src/App.vue)